# I may have a virus? email sent from my gmail to all my contacts

Tags: macos, mac, virus

I have a mac and all my gmail contacts were apparently sent a link from my gmail account.  I'm worried I have a virus, but I didn't think they had viruses on macs.  What can I do?  I sent out an email to all my contacts saying not to open it, and changed my gmail password, but if my computer has a virus my new password might not be safe either.  What can I do?  Could they have gotten access to all my past emails?  There is nothing in my sent emails... I don't even see the spam emails I sent out.

Thanks

Comment: An off-topic answer, as it relates to Gmail directly, not to your question about a virus on a Mac: Gmail can tell you if someone used the Gmail website with your credentials. At the bottom of the Gmail website click "Details" after "Last account activity". Anything there that is not you?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes there was a login from Israel on there, which means they must have stolen my password and used it there.

Comment: At least that might give you some IP address to report to Gmail, though that might very well be some compromised computer itself (some botnet doing the dirty work). Did you use Gmail on any other computer but your own? Any comment on Wil's suggestions?

Comment: And: you did (and do) have a hard-to-guess password, right?

Comment: @Arjan not ruling it out, but the majority of these "attacks" come from signing up to dodgy looking websites with your email address and the same password as you use for that email account - they filter out common services such as hotmail and gmail then logon and send spam... many even have things in the terms and conditions saying that you give them permission to do it... scary!

Comment: Yep, @Wil, [that's how things work](http://xkcd.com/792/)... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan +1 love it! - saw that a bit earlier from someone on Twitter, made me laugh! Love their more  sysadmin/techy ones!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible for Macs to get malware, but it is unlikely.

The most likely reason is that you used a third party service that asked for your credentials, and, it was less than honest - saved your details, logged on to Gmail and did this.

If they had logged in to your Gmail account, they could get access to all your emails, however, most likely this was a highly automated service and they had no reason to look at your emails.

Comment: Hmmm, wondering about that downvote... Why?